# Escape characters in XML while parsing in python

Tags: python-3.x, xml

I would like to parse the following XML in python :

```
<root>
<node attrib="abc<>2"/>
</root>
```

I am using xml.etree.Elementree.fromstring() method.
I am getting an error at "c" saying invalid token found. This is due to the presence of "<>” after "c".

Can anyone help to solve this Error ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Change `<` to `&lt;`, perhaps? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML#Escaping

Comment: Is there a way to escape characters in attrib value only and not from the actual tags ?

Comment: Is there a problem? Just open the XML in a text editor and fix the single `<` that needs to be changed.

Comment: I have more than 4000 such files to process. That would be really tedious to do manually. 

Comment: Maybe you can use regular expressions to search and replace only in attribute values.